# Adding a JPanel from a different class

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to add a simple `JPanel` from a different class with only a `JButton` and a `JTextArea` into the GUI.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for the swing application and there are no errors. However, the `JPanel` simply doesn't appear/isn't shown.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ContainerAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ContainerEvent;

public class GUI {
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JPanel mainInner;


public GUI() {
    mainPanel.addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
            super.componentAdded(e);
            System.out.println("component Added");
        }
    });
}

public void start() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    frame.setContentPane(new GUI().mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    InnerPanel inner = new InnerPanel();
    mainInner = inner.getMainInner();

    inner.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(mainInner, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The component listener shows that the component has been added, yet it isn't shown.

Comment: Components would typically be added to a GUI before it ever appears.  You might use a `CardLayout` to ensure they are not visible before being needed by the user. General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It is not possible to run your code. Classs InnerPanel is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `mainPanel` to `frame`:

```
frame.add(mainPanel);
```